# Java, Spring boot, Swagger and form base authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I've created rest-api with BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint. It looks like this

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" +getRealmName());
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("Marketplace");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

As you have noticed I'm using "FormBased" header in order avoid browser's ugly authorization window. Front-end Angular application uses its own authorization form.
It works fine, but I'm also using Swagger as self describing tool for rest-api. With Swagger and such header (`response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased");`) I have a problem. Swagger returns 401 error because browser do not suggests authorization window.
Is there any way use Swagger with header (`response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased")`;) instead of (`response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" +getRealmName());`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for this problem. The point is that I had wrong security configuration in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The configuration secured any request like this

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/registration/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/dictionary/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/common/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/advert_public/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/company_public/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasRole(DEFAULT_ROLE)
        .and().httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
```

And this way Swagger entry point required login/password too.

Now I've rewrote configuration to secure particular methods in my api and Swagger works fine

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/advert/**").hasRole(DEFAULT_ROLE)
        .antMatchers("/api/company/**").hasRole(DEFAULT_ROLE)
        .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole(DEFAULT_ROLE)
        .and().httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
```

As you could see there is no config option like `.anyRequest().hasRole(DEFAULT_ROLE)`